# How to access to the return value from a function

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, return-value

I'm trying to make an application that  can apply  sound effects on audio file using PyQt5 module
i developed the module it contain function that  apply  the effect and return  the new value of the signal **y**

I  get  stuck  on how to  get  the return value from the module function

effrets.py

for example this function can apply  reverberation effects on audio  file

```
def revebration1(y,sr,retard,pert):
    T = int(retard*sr)
    print(T)
    x = np.zeros(len(y)+T)
    x[0:len(y)] = y
    x[T::] += pert*y
    sd.play(x,sr)
    return x
```

app.py

When  i click button1  i  want to access to access to the value of **x** returned by **revebration1**

```
class AppDemo(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(1000,1000)
        self.label = QLabel('const', self)
        self.layout1=QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout2=QVBoxLayout()
        #buttons
        self.button1 = QPushButton('importer',self)
        self.button1.move(300,300)
        self.layout1.addWidget(self.button1,1)
        #self.button1.clicked.connect(self.lambda)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.tele)    

   def tele(self):
   # I don't know how to  access to the return value of  revebration1 function in order to  continue     building  my  app
```

Comment: You need to actually call the function. Doing so executes the code inside it and returns the value indicated by the `return` statement. Having said that, this seems like pretty basic Python knowledge.

Comment: `value = revebration1(y,sr,retard,pert)` assigns the return value to the variable `value`

Comment: No need for the lambda - just call the function and use it's returned value.

Answer (score 0):

To access returned value of the function you have to call that function

self.funcResult = revebration1(y,sr,retard,pert) - that's it

Answer (score -1):

revebrationReturnedValue = revebration1(y,sr,retard,pert)